# Showing EPS Image

Tags: ios, eps

I want to show EPS images inside IOS application, But we don't want to convert these in any other format.These are the vector images, and cannot be converted to raster images. I want to demonstrate the ability to ZOOM images without distortion.

So is there any way to do this, I am using HTML an Phonegap for developing the app.

Answer (score -1):

Convert them to SVG. Vector graphics AND supported by HTML5/Webkit...

Comment: What all tools you suggest for conversion through command line or programmatically?

Comment: ImageMagick. I think Ghostscript does it too.

Comment: Doesn't seems to be working any of the softwares....When i tried to convert the EPS images using those softwares it is converting to some blank SVG image....Please guys tell me some good software/tool for EPS to SVG conversion.

Answer (score -2):

I would use InkScape. It's an open source application that is basically Adobe Illustrator light. Has many of the same functionality as AI but without the robust toolset.